# Ubuntu One windows Uninstall.exe file missing

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, uninstall

I want to uninstall Ubuntu One but unistall.exe file is missing in folder.

Now I try to reinstall from installer to get uninstall.exe file, but same problem: the installer do not install unistall.exe file, but create a shortcut for uninstalling. Shortcut do not work because main unistall.exe file is still missing.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot and install again?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to indicate the install process is crashing somehow before the uninstaller is created.

You can uninstall ubuntu one manually. What version of windows are you using? (Some steps change depending on it)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows's *Control Panel*, go to *Software* (or *Add/Remove Programs*) and try to uninstall it there. This often works for removing Windows software that cannot otherwise be easily uninstalled.